# jQuery : mousemove on 'body', and avoid 'menu' element

Tags: jquery

is there a possibility to use the mousemove on the 'body', and avoid at the same time an element of the DOM, like the div 'menu' ?
The idea is to show the 'prev' or 'next' arrow in the background, but hide it -> if we enter in the menu element.

I tried this :

> $('body').not('#menu').bind('mousemove', function(e){

but it didn't work out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').bind('mousemove', function(e){
 // Your Code to handle Mouse Move Globally.
});

$('#menu').bind('mousemove', function(e){
 // Your Code to handle Mouse Move on the #Menu.
 //##################
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, i tried 'display none'  on the divs that contain the prev and next buttons, but they're still visible... $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
 $('#prev, #next').css({'display':'none'});

Comment: @Paul: Unless you post the code you are using, it is very difficult to analyze the cause of the error.

Comment: @Cybernate: Alright, sorry, i don't use correctly the 'indent' and stuff of the comment window, so the code is usually a mess in here ;-) my code :
>$('body').bind('mousemove', function(e){      
  var deuxTiers = $(window).width()*(2/3),  
  unTiers = $(window).width()*(1/3),  
  zoneYmin = $(window).height()*(1/3),  
          zoneYmax = $(window).height()*(2/3)+100,  
          marge = 15,  
          posX = e.pageX-marge,  
          posY = e.pageY-marge;  
          (see next comment...)

Comment: if (e.pageX>deuxTiers && e.pageY>zoneYmin && e.pageY<zoneYmax) {
  $('#prec').fadeOut();
  $('#suiv').fadeIn();
  $('#suiv').css({'left':posX, 'top':posY, 'cursor':'none'})
          } else if(e.pageX<unTiers && e.pageY>zoneYmin && e.pageY<zoneYmax) {
  $('#prec').fadeIn();
  $('#suiv').fadeOut();
  $('#prec').css({'left':posX, 'top':posY, 'cursor':'none'})
  } else {
  $('#prec, #suiv').css({'display':'none'});
  }
  });


>$('#conteneur').bind('mousemove', function(e){      
 $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});  
 $('#prec, #suiv').css({'display':'none'});  
  e.stopPropagation();  
});

Comment: I quickly put some HTML to match the JS and the elements #prec, #suiv go hidden when I move the mouse on #conteneur

Comment: @Cybernate: are you sure the cursor was outside the specific area that change the cursor image? because i still have the 'prec' image when i'm inside this specific area. Two third in 'y' and 'x' ... no?